# How to root Samsung Galaxy A5 (SM-A500H) running Android 6.0.1

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have Galaxy A5 (SM-A500H) When I was on Lollipop I rooted it using kingroot apk. Yesterday I upgraded to 6.0.1 from [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/88174/A500HXXU1CPH2_A500HOXY1CPH2_CAC/). And it has `SS/pc` not sure if that prevent rooting or anything like that, I'm using Uzbekistan's version.

Kingroot apk no longer works, it gets to 65% then tells me that no rooting strategy works. Kingroot exe seems to be offered exclusively in Chinese these days so I cannot use it.

The [chainfire](https://download.chainfire.eu/656/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-a53g-a53gxx-sma500h.zip) version doesn't work, if I use it, I get a little red warning on booting screen that I have breached the warranty or something like that, I don't care about the error but the phone won't boot, the only way to exit, is to press volume down and power and home button and wait like 10 seconds, enter download mode and flash the Sammobile firmware again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odin, this [TWRP recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/development/recovery-samsung-galaxy-a52015-sm-a500f-t3360802) and a [SuperSU](http://supersu.com/download) flashable zip (the thread also supplies one but it seems to be for Lollipop) should be all you need.

P.S. As of version 2.78, SuperSU is fully under the control of Chinese firm CCMT - use 2.76 if you don't trust that.

Comment: Can I use supersu from playstore? I bought that long ago to support the developer or it wont be installed unless the phone is rooted? i forgot since for the last few years I have been using kingroot exclusively

Comment: You should be able to restore Pro purchase after rooting. Directly installing SuperSU from store will not root the phone, mind you.